# Error after checkout in Magento 2.4.5 after switching to PHP 8.1 "Something went wrong with your reuqest"

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.5, php8

we have updated Magento from 2.4.4 to Magento 2.4.5 on our staging instance.

Now after switching to PHP 8.1 during checkout we get the error message "Something went wrong with your request".

When switching back to PHP 7.4 all works well. The error logs do not show anything related. Does anyone possibly have an idea where to look for a fix?

We switched already to Luma Theme but no sucess.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the browser developer tool, switch to the Network tab, go to the checkout page, and perform checkout. I think you will see the request (red color) which caused the error in the network tab.

Comment: Found the culprit another way. It was the not-updated Active Campaign extension. Updating the same did the job.

Comment: Glad to hear your issue resolved!